# Keyboard Conflicts in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using MATLAB R2015a. In Home --> Environment --> Preferences --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts, there is a conflict in that both Save and Save Workspace appear to be mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. What is supposed to happen in the case of a conflict? It appears that -  in this instance -  it chooses the top option. I've found that only the variable I had open at the time of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> has been saved, and thus I've lost the rest of them.

Comment: Update: removing the mapping to "Save" - which should resolve the conflict - still has not lead to Cntrl + S saving the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.

What command is run depends on where the window focus is.

- **Editor:** Save open .m file.
- **Command Window:** Save all variables from workspace.
- **Variable viewer:** Save current open variable.